Should i be worried about these wall cracks around the windows?
Here are the pictures
I found some vertical cracks around two windows in the exterior. both on the same side of the house and are pretty close to each other. Is there a structural issue? How do i go about filling them up?

Where you are in the world is important to determining if the cracks should be any concern.
If you are in an area where sinkholes are common, the cracks could be an early sign of soil movement. They can be filled and painted, but you should keep an eye on them. If they come back and get bigger,and are accompanied by the window getting difficult to open and close or cracking, you may want to consult with a company that stabilizes foundations. Your insurance may cover the expenses for inspection and correction.
Often new home settling will result in cracks around windows and doors. If you fill them and nothing else happens, they were just normal settling of a home. Use some latex caulk suitable for exterior use. and paint when dry.

I agree with RMDman if it's new construction you see the occasional cracks above windows and doorways and they are easily addressed with some paintable silicone. Now if it's an older house and these cracks just started appearing then you may have an issue. If you have any big excavating jobs around or any newly sprung blasting zones (normally they are associated with big road building projects)these can cause minor cracks also. If you are experiencing moisture inside the window then you have a whole new set of issues which might cost you some money. Just keep an eye on them and see if they get larger or if you have moisture issues like damp drywall or plaster.
